# Java scanner not storing string properly

Tags: java

I am trying to create a menu in the console and have the user select an option, for some reason when I run the application it goes straight to the else, bypassing options a-d.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserChoice {


 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean status = true;
    while (status == true)
    {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("MENU");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("A : String Functions");
    System.out.println("B : Simple Arithmetic Functions");
    System.out.println("C : Temperature Conversion");
    System.out.println("D : Sequences");
    System.out.println("E : Exit Application");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please make a selection.");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice =null;
    choice = keyboard.nextLine();





    if (choice == "a" || choice == "A")
    {
        StringFunctions();
    }

    else if (choice == "b" || choice == "B")
    {
        ArithmeticFunctions();
    }

    else if (choice == "c" || choice == "C")
    {
        TemperatureConversion();
    }

    else if (choice == "d" || choice == "D")
    {
        Sequences();
    }

    else if (choice == "e" || choice == "E")
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid selection, please choose again.");

    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All String/Object comparisons should use `equals()` method instead of `==` (except String literals)

```
if (choice.equals("a") || choice .equals( "A")){....}
```

Apply same change to other else/if blocks also.

`==` compares reference equality. `equals()` method checks for content equality.

Comment: Omg tysm you're a lifesaver! I can't believe it was such a simple mistake :P I've been scratching my head for an hour haha

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure that at least one character is entered:

```
   String choiceString ="";
   while(choiceString.length() <1){
         choiceString = keyboard.nextLine();
   }
```

Once done, you may want to get the first character from the string as:

```
   char choice = choiceString.charAt(0);
```

now since your choice is char, you may write your conditions using single quote as below:

```
   if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A'){
    .......
    ......
```

Also if you want, you want to change the case of String entered to upper or lower case, get the char and then use simpler conditions as below:

```
      char choice = choiceString.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
      if (choice == 'A'){ 
       .....
      }else if(...
```